# Typescript error when multiple optional types are used

Tags: javascript, typescript

This an example of the error:

```
interface Block {
  id: string;
}

interface TitleBlock extends Block  {
  data: {
    text: "hi",
    icon: "hi-icon"
  }
}

interface SubtitleBlock extends Block  {
  data: {
    text: "goodbye",
  }
}

interface CommentBlock extends Block {
  author: string; 
}

type BlockTypes = TitleBlock | SubtitleBlock | CommentBlock

function mapper(block : BlockTypes) {
    if(block?.data?.text){  // TS Error here!!! 
      /** do something */
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIBsD2CDWyDeAsAFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3CQL4kmiSyIoAVYGHQQM2PBAAekEBVposuMkVLIKcMHBqqyZSDJoAiABbAjAGhJ7yCTCGNmAtMDsgj15J2Lfu4aPBIyADKAK4ARmDCouLK0rLyihIqnhpaOp768cZMmJgU4QCeEJae3r7EPAH8yADCmAC2DRDgsZIyLYltBJ5woWAmmFA09IwgrMgcXMRghQAOKG0C8xAKALzIQiJiSngAPiERUdvdB-VNLWBt0zChIAhR9sgNcHMLUAAU4bvINEsrtAAlD01GRgDAvrsAPwAOjScFhBjAgPwZAA9GjNsFkABRKBQIbIEzQCAAQnJk1BejRACoaepMHRGhABsxkDS0ZkvBwgA)

I want to do something in the function when the block has a specific attribute but TS does not allow me to do so even when there are type in BlockTypes that have that property.

What is the best way to manage this types of functionalities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) only guards against `null` and `undefined`; it does not  filter a [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) expression to those members known to contain that key.  See [this comment in Microsoft/TypeScript#33736](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33736#issuecomment-543932468) for a canonical answer.

---

The issue is that object types in TypeScript are *open* and are allowed to contain more properties than the compiler knows about.  So if `block.data` is truthy, it unfortunately does not imply that `block.data.text` exists:

```
const oof = {
  id: "x",
  author: "weirdo",
  data: 123
}
mapper(oof); // accepted
```

Here `oof` is a valid `CommentBlock`, and so `mapper(oof)` is allowed, and `oof.data` is truthy, but `oof.data.text` is `undefined`, and you will have a problem if you try to treat it like a `string`.

So it would be *unsound* (that is, not type safe) to allow optional chaining to filter unions the way you want.

---

The workaround here, if you don't think that `oof`-like cases are likely, is to use [the `in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
function mapper(block: BlockTypes) {
  if ("data" in block) {
    block.data.text.toUpperCase()
  }
}
```

This works fine with no compiler error.  Of course, it's still unsound in exactly the same way as narrowing with `?.` would be... if you call `mapper(oof)` there are no compiler errors but you will get a runtime error.  So you should be careful.

It's a little weird that TypeScript allows `in` to behave this way but does not allow other similar constructs.  You can read the discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#10485](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485) to see why that happened. Mostly it seems to be that when people write `"foo" in bar` they rarely do the wrong thing with it, but that other constructs like `bar.foo && bar.foo.baz` are misused more often.  But that's according to the TS team, not me. ‍♂️

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIBsD2CDWyDeAsAFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3CQL4kmiSyIoAVYGHQQM2PBAAekEBVposuAiTIU4YODSKkyySDJoAiABbAjAGlV7gCTCGNmAtLftHrnYp+7ho8JMgAygCuAEZgwqLiytKy8ooSKrrqmtrWZAZgxkyYmBShAJ4Qlh4cXMQ8fvzIAMKYALb1EODRkjLN8a1JZHDBYCaYUDT0jCCsZcQkYAUADiitArMQCgC8yEIiYkp4AD5BYRGbXXt1jc1greV2IPTIuTDIazpklMZSJbq9-YPGAO4QwCgFEwHzUGi0yAAjAAmADME3qcBmcygAAp7gBKNiTYgwYIgBARezIRHI6Co0LbGgLJa0DHdcgPVFGFJwIzkEDISkSenPPTc3AAOlZgsyoswAFUyVAanBaBBURjSl4gA)